# Where do I put a custom function for multiple themes

Tags: theming

I have two 2 themes so two template.php. I have a function that I use in both themes. I don't want to write it twice.
Where do I put it ?

Comment: Choose the file.

Answer (score 3):

You can put it in a module, or set up your themes so that they are sub themes of a main theme.

Answer (score -1):

What about creating a function.php and in default/settings.php writting "require 'function.php';" ?

Comment: at least tell why